# Can anybody explain about following structure

Tags: c, linux-kernel

What is the use of the below structure in linux kernel? I need to know it because I need to add a variable inside this structure.

```
static const struct modversion_info ____versions[]
```

Answer (score 2):

It includes symbols referenced by the module and their checksums, when the module is inserted those symbols are checked to make sure the module is compiled for the running kernel.

On Ubnutu the `kernel-headers` package contains this file which has all the symbols exported by the kernel and their checksums, you should be able to find this file if you compiled your own kernel too

```
usr/src/linux-headers-2.6.38-generic/Module.symvers
```

Note, I'm not sure what you're trying to do but you shouldn't be adding symbols to your module, when you compile a module this structure is generated for you.

Comment: First of all thank you for response and how to calculate checksum of a function?

Comment: The checksum calculation is normally done while "make modules" in the kernel build. I think you need to clarify (much?) more about what you are trying to achieve. You don't just add things to this struct willy nilly, it's part of the "modprobe" or "insmod" to add things to this.

Comment: @MatsPetersson so true, but I thought I just answer the part about the structure, added a note too.

Comment: Thanks both of you for giving clarity on this structure. I got clarified and I need not to modify this any more.